# Sharepoint 2013 keep traking of Document sharing

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, document-library

I want to keep a track of sharing documents in Document library. Is there any feature available in sharepoint for this?

How can I Do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the new Security events introduced in SharePoint 2013. 
On every **GroupUserAdded, GroupUserDeleted, RoleAssignmentAdded, RoleAssignmentDeleted** event you can add an entry to a list or database that will help you track the sharing of document.

Security events available to leverage in SharePoint 2013 are given [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurityeventreceiver_members.aspx).

A tutorial on how to do this is given [here](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/12/27/create-a-groupuseradded-eventreceiverspsecurityeventreceiver-in-sharepoint-2013/).

Answer (score 0):

You can enable auditing for each site collection for which you want to collect data. Instructions for doing so are available at https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-a9920c97-38c0-44f2-8bcb-4cf1e2ae22d2

This provides data on (depending upon what you enable):

- Documents being opened or downloaded, list items being viewed
- Documents or items being edited
- Documents or items being checked out or checked in
- Documents or items being moved or copied to other locations within SharePoint
- Documents or items being deleted or restored
- Content types or columns being edited
- Site content being searched
- Site users or permissions being edited.